# Hi, I have created a class with 3 public variables but whenever i try to use String Interpolation i get an error telling the property doesnt exist

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, data-binding, string-interpolation

This is the error i get for the 'imagePath' Property and it is the same for all the other 2 properties:

```
src/app/recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component.html:2:44 - error TS2339: Property 
'imagePath' does not exist on type 'Receta[]'.

2   <img class="card-img-top" src="{{recipes.imagePath}}" alt="{{recipes.name}}">
                                         ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component.ts:5:16
   5   templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component RecipeListComponent.
```

This is my recipe.models.ts

```js
export class Receta {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public imagePath: string;

    constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

This is my recipe-list.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Receta} from '../recipe.model';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-recipe-list',
     templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes: Receta[] = [
        new Receta('name', 'test', 'url')
    ];
  
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

And this is the recipe-list.component.html where i try to use string interpolation to display the name, description and image path dynamically

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{recipes.imagePath}}" alt=" 
    {{recipes.name}}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{recipes.name}} </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{recipes.description}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>

<app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
```

I am new in Angular and typescript so please tell me if im making a silly mistake.
Can someone help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `recipes` is a list (Receta[]), not a single Receta.

You need to loop through all the recipes if you want to create a `card` for every one of them. You might find this helpful https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Here's how you'd use it:

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{recipe.imagePath}}" alt=" 
    {{recipe.name}}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{recipe.name}} </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Igli did this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line with recipes: Receta[] = [new Receta('name', 'test', 'url')   ]; --> recipes: Receta = [new Receta('name', 'test', 'url')   ];

recipes is a only a Receta types winngle object